# Style transfer on large image. (in chunks?)

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, style-transfer

I am looking into various style transfer models and I noted that they all have limited resolution (when running on Pixel 3, for example, I couldn't go beyond 1,024x1,024, OOM otherwise).

I've noticed a few apps (eg [this app](https://medium.com/@tinyline/copista-on-device-high-resolution-image-style-transfer-3a34377a8a2d)) which appear to be doing style transfer for up to ~10MP images, these apps also show progress bar which I guess means that they don't just call a single tensorflow "run" method for entire image as otherwise they won't know how much was processed.

I would guess they are using some sort of tiling, but naively splitting the image into 256x256 produces inconsistent style (not just on the borders).

As this seems like an obvious problem I tried to find any publications about this, but I couldn't find any. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess people split the model into multiple ones (for VGG it is easy to do manually, eg. via layers) and then use model_summary Keras function (or benchmarks) to estimate relative time it takes for each step and thus guide progress bar. Such separation probably also saves memory as tensorflow lite might not be clever enough to reuse memory storing intermediate activations from lower layers once they are not needed.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question though?